# From a subscribed list how get users who only subscribed to English channels

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have table having records of users subscribed to both English and Hindi channels, I want only whose users who subcribed to English

```
+--------+------+------+------+
| id | userid | Subscribedto |   
+--------+------+------+------+
|  1 |   1     |   English   |
|  2 |   2     |   English   |
|  3 |   1     |   Hindi     |
|  4 |   3     |   English   |
|  4 |   3     |   Hindi     |
|  5 |   4     |   English   |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

So the result will be

```
+--------+------+------+------+
| id | userid | Subscribedto |   
+--------+------+------+------+
|  2 |   2     |   English   |
|  5 |   4     |   English   |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Why there is no id 1 and 4 in result table? they also subscribed to English

Comment: You can do `select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME where Subscribedto='English';`

Comment: I think you mean "subscribed only to English"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are not nulls in the column `subscribedto` you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where userid = t.userid and subscribedto <> 'English'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KWEWHmXXCS9BkcC4Zdra8/0).
Results:

```
| id  | userid | subscribedto |
| --- | ------ | ------------ |
| 2   | 2      | English      |
| 5   | 4      | English      |
```

You can also add to the where clause the condition `subscribedto = 'English'`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where subscribedto = 'English' and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where userid = t.userid and subscribedto <> 'English'
)
```

The result is the same but this version may be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,subscribed_to VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE KEY(user_id,subscribed_to)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'English'),
(2,2,'English'),
(3,1,'Hindi'),
(4,3,'English'),
(5,3,'Hindi'),
(6,4,'English');

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.subscribed_to <> x.subscribed_to 
 WHERE x.subscribed_to = 'English' 
   AND y.id IS NULL;

+----+---------+---------------+
| id | user_id | subscribed_to |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  2 |       2 | English       |
|  6 |       4 | English       |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Analytic function will do this in single table scan, no expensive joins. It will work in Hive:

```
SELECT id, userid, subscribedto
FROM
(
SELECT id, userid, subscribedto,
       max(case when subscribedto != 'English' then true else false end) over(partition by userid ) subscribed_not_english
  FROM my_table s
)s 
WHERE NOT subscribed_not_english
```